# Linear mixed model: should I define all interactions and main effects in a factorial design?

Tags: mixed-model, spss

I have a 2 x 2 x 2 design, and I only want to analyse main effects and two-way interactions, not the three-way interaction.

Using SPSS MIXED, should I still define the three-way interaction and just ignore its output, or leave it out of the model entirely?

Comment: Does 2x2x2 refer to fixed effects?

Comment: @amoeba Yes, all fixed effects.

Comment: You've not explained what makes this a mixed model. That said, if you are not interested in the 3-way interaction, then don't include it. There is no statistical need to include higher order terms in a model, only that lower order terms be included if you are testing higher order ones.

Comment: @dbwilson Thanks. I'm using the 2x2x2 as an example, so just assume that at least on is repeated measures and the others are independent.

Comment: @dbwilson What I don't understand is why, when I delete the higher-order interaction terms from the model, my F values do up, and my p values go down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't include the three-way interaction if you aren't interested in it, or if it isn't significant.

The reason the F values are higher (and the corresponding p-values lower) in the model without the higher-order interaction is that there is more variability to be explained by the remaining effects in the reduced model.

Including the three-way interaction is essentially masking some of the variation explained by the main effects and two-way interactions. This loss of information is unhelpful and unnecessary if the three-way interaction is not significant.

Comment: The tests of 'main effects' when an interaction term is not included are tests of different hypotheses than the 'main effects' when an interaction term is in the model.

Comment: In an unbalanced design (different sample sizes across conditions), the interaction terms are not orthogonal to the main effects. As such, a model with interaction terms may change the main effects substantially (or similarly, the 3-way interaction may change the 2-way interactions). In such a case, you generally want to be interpreting the main effects from a model that doesn't have the interactions.